# presentViewController with the tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, presentviewcontroller

I have a app which has a tabbar which is presented in most of the `ViewControllers`. The problem is its not showing in an `viewController` which i'm presenting by this code.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:songsViewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

I'm using the `presentViewController` instead of the `pushViewcontroller`, cause i want to customize the `navigationBar` in this view.

How can i present my standard tabbar which i've created using `storyboard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `presentViewController:animated:completion`, you are presenting the view controller modally, meaning it is not being contained within any of your existing containers like a `UITabBarController` or anything like that. So if you want something to show up when you present a `UIViewController` modally, it must be contained within the view controller that you're modally presenting. So from the looks of it, you're simply presenting a `UINavigationController` with your `songsViewController` contained within it. If you want to keep your `UITabBar` showing, either you need to add one to the view you're presenting, or you need to change your code so that you're not presenting a view controller modally here. And to add a second `UITabBar` for the modal view that matches the `UITabBar` that you were already presenting, it will make your app work rather strangely, so I would suggest trying to change it so you're not having to present a modal view at all.