# Present programmatically a UIViewController (embed in an UITabBarController) at indexpath.item

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I need to present programmatically a specific ViewController that contains informations depending on its row / item (from a UICollectionView).
But this ViewController is embed in a TabBarController and I don't see how to get the informations contained in an array.

I'm used to present it directly in a UITableViewRowAction like this :

```
    let MyEditingController = MySpecificController()

    MyEditingController.delegate = self

    MyEditingController.Object = arrayOfObjects[indexPath.item]

    let navController = CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: MyEditingController)

    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This will present correctly MySpecificController but how to present this Controller when it needs to be embed in a UITabBarController : MySpecificController should be the first item of 4 screens displayed by this TabBar.

Any idea/suggestion ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. Are you trying to programmatically add a new controller to the TabBar (adding a new icon in it), or maybe you're looking for a UINavigationController (back arrow at the top of the screen)? If you could sketch something that would be better.

Comment: On one hand, I have a collectionView : each item/row of it has a "more" button that I can handle to present informations.
On the other hand : a tapBar with 4 screens, The 1st screen is presenting the informations I want to show.

Comment: I'm able to do it usually with navcontroller but from UIviewcontroller to other UIViewController, not from UIViewController to UITabBarController

Comment: @AndreaGottardo, it could be like this : https://imgur.com/a/lnVD6RM

Comment: @Creanomy You can present a `UITabBarController` instead. As I understand, you need to present a specific `UIViewController` from the `UITabBarController`, right?

Comment: @Mannopson The only answer I found is quite similar to my problem... https://stackoverflow.com/a/21535384/8162027
Have also a look to this image :
https://imgur.com/a/lnVD6RM

Comment: @Creanomy What did you tried so far? If you can add some code, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Mannopson : This is the way I push a TapBar from a classical VC with a custom transition :
`fileprivate func sendMain() {
        let TapBar = MainTabBarController()
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.3
        transition.type = CATransitionType.push
        transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        present(TapBar, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about my question....
I did a "noob" mistake, the answer was under my noze : I refactored the way I builded my TabBar as I could reach each of my VC and of course, I "simply" changed my presentedViewController....
Now, it just works perfectly
Damned ! sorry for those who tried to help me.